# kendo grid MVVM Inline Edit Focus issue after updating field data

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

We are trying to create Kendo Grid with all the fields in In-line edit mode. We are facing issue when edit field tab change not moving to next control.

Steps to repeat issue:

1. Edit text in first cell
2. Click on tab key
3. Losing focus from grid.

Please help to resolve.

http://jsfiddle.net/suniltvl/eUhP5/

**JS:**

```
var vm = kendo.observable({

    roles: [{
        firstname: "test",
        lastname: "test",
        username: "test",
    }, {
        firstname: "test1",
        lastname: "test1",
        username: "test1",
    }, {
        firstname: "test2",
        lastname: "test2",
        username: "test2",
    }]

});

kendo.bind($("#people"), vm);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="people">
    <div data-role="grid" data-bind="source: roles" data-row-template="role-template" data-columns='[{"field": "firstName", "title": "First Name"}, 
                        {"field": "lastName", "title": "Last Name"}, 
{"field": "username", "title": "user name"}]'></div>
</div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="role-template">
    < tr class = "k-grid-edit-row" > < td > < input type = "text"
    class = "k-textbox"
    data - bind = "value:firstname" / > < /td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  class="k-textbox"  data-bind="value:lastname"/ > < /td>
    <td>
      <input type="text"  class="k-textbox"  data-bind="value:username"/ > < /td>

    </tr >
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kendo Grid's [navigatable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-navigatable) property turns on keyboard navigation of the grid.  My [Grid Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rick_Mortensen/Wtrb4/7) demonstrates using this property.  In general when you define a grid, it is defined with each cell as a display only element, and Kendo will dynamically display the input element when the user tabs/clicks on that cell.

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: ds,
    navigatable: true,
    pageable: true,
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    reorderable: true,
    editable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "FirstName",
        width: 90,
        title: "First Name"
    }, {
        field: "LastName",
        width: 200,
        title: "Last Name"
    }, {
        field: "City",
        width: 200
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```